# how can the textbox width be reduced?

Tags: html, maxlength, inputbox

Can I reduce the textbox width without using classes?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" style="3px"/>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
<input type="text" style="width:50px;"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Is not nice to define textbox width without using CSS, be warned ;-)

```
<input type="text" name="d" value="4" size="4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

rows and cols are required attributes, so you should have them whether you really need them or not. They set the number of rows and number of columns respectively.

http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/textarea/

Comment: Thought that was only for textareas

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type='text' 
       name='t1'
       id='t1'
       maxlength=10
       placeholder='typing some text' >
<p></p>
```

This is the text box, it has a fixed length of 10 characters, and if you can try but this text box does not contain maximum length 10 character